# Elm: how to update Dict inside Dict if the structure is dynamic ( has varying depth )?

Tags: elm

Given the following fileSystem structure :

```
type alias FolderName = String

type Folder
    = Folder
        { folderName : String
        , childFolders : Dict FolderName Folder
        }

type alias FileSystem =
    Dict FolderName Folder


fileSystem : FildeSystem
fileSystem =
    Dict.formList
        [ ( "parent1"
          , Folder
                { folderName = "parent1"
                , childFolders =
                    Dict.fromList
                        [ ( "child1", Folder { folderName = "child1", childFolders = Dict.empty } )
                        , ( "child2", Folder { folderName = "child2", childFolders = Dict.empty } )
                        , ( "child3"
                          , Folder
                                { folderName = "child3"
                                , childFolders =
                                    Dict.formList
                                        [ ( "sub-child_of_child3", Folder { folderName = "sub-child_of_child3", childFolders = Dict.empty } )
                                        ]
                                }
                          )
                        ]
                }
          )
        ]
```

I want to be able to ***create new folders dynamically*** by calling a function and **passing in the location** where i want the new folder to be created.. the **folder's name** and also the **fileSystem Dict**. Something like this:

```
createFolder: String -> FileSystem -> FolderName -> FileSystem
createFolder "parent1/child3/sub-child_of_child3" fileSystem "DynamicallyCreated"
```

Because there is no way to know upfront what the `fileSystem Dict` looks like, and because this is elm (`no for loops`) - i think the only way to do this, is using recursion.

**The code:**

```
createFolder location fileSystem newFolderName=
    let 
        locationAsArray = String.split "/" location
    in
                     // first find the dict value. (that is the value of 'sub-child_of_child3' key, inside 'child3' Dict.)

        findDictValueBasedOnLocation locationAsArray fileSystem

                     // then update the 'sub-child_of_child3' by inserting the newFolder. 
            |> (\ x -> { x | childFolders = Dict.insert newFolderName Folder { folderName = newFolderName, childFolders = Dict.empty } x.childFolders

                     // but how to reconsturct the child3, partent1 and finally the fileSystem now? Because this function it's supose to return a new fileSystem that contains the newly created folder.
```

**find corresponding dict with recursion:**

```
findDictValueBasedOnLocation listDictKeys currentDict =
    let
        currentKey =
            List.head listDictKeys

        remainingKeys =
            List.tail listDictKeys
    in
        -- when there is only one element in the listDictKeys  that is: ["sub-child_of_child3"]-  the recursive call stops/
        if List.length listDictKeys == 1 then
           Dict.get currentKey currentDict
                |> Maybe.withDefault -- what to add here?
        else
            let
                nextDict =
                    Dict.get currentKey currentDict
                        |> Maybe.withDefault --what to add here ?-  don't know the type ..
            in
                -- recursive call with the remaining listDictKeys and nextDict which is in fact the current Dict value.
                findDictValueBasedOnContext remainingKeys nextDict
```

You can see 2 big problems here:

1. the Dict.get returns a Maybe and i don't know how to deal with that in recursion.
2. even if i manage to find the corresponding part of the Dict and update it by creating the new folder; - How do i update what i have now on the higher levels like `parent1`?  ex: - keep in mind that this update could happen on level as deep as 20.. how do I tell to level 3 2, 1 about this update?

I don't necessarily try to make this code work. I you have another approach to this it's even better.

And couldn't find examples of updating or creating Dicts inside Dicts dynamically.

I'm battling this problem for 2-3 days now.

First i tried using records instead of Dicts - because they allow for different types inside them. But I coudn't use `record."someString"` to access it's value - like in javascript. So no luck with records. Dicts seem more promising .. hope someone knows how to to solve this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice challenge!
First of all, you are dealing with recursive types ([more on those here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/master/hints/recursive-alias.md)). A `Folder` contains a `Dict FolderName Folder`, so indeed you need some strong typing here.

And you are looking to do recursive updates on a `Dict` inside a `Dict`.

Below you can find a sample solution code, which you can copy/paste to http://elm-lang.org/try

The inner workings of the different functions are explained in the code itself.

Some comments:

- For updating a `Dict`, a common pattern is to provide a key + an update function to the entire `Dict` ([see here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Dict#update) for docs on `Dict.update`). This is more efficient that the 3-step approach of 1) retrieve a record to update, 2) change the record and 3) putting it back in the `Dict`
- If any of the nodes in the provided path fail, then the function will simply return an unchanged `FileSystem`
- If `newFolderName` already exists, the entire existing folder with that name (*including all child folders*) will be replaced

Hope this helps to understand some of the functions in Elm.

Code example:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Dict exposing (Dict)

---- TYPES
type alias FolderName = String

type Folder
    = Folder
        { folderName : FolderName
        , childFolders : FileSystem
        }

type alias FileSystem =
    Dict FolderName Folder


{- MAIN FUNCTION: 
takes the first element in the path
and tries to do a recursive update on the children of the fileSystem
-}
insertFolder: String -> FolderName -> FileSystem -> FileSystem
insertFolder path newFolderName fileSystem =
  let
    nodeList = String.split "/" path
  in
    case nodeList of
      node :: rest ->
        -- if we have nodes, do recursive update on folders
        fileSystem
        |> Dict.update node (Maybe.map <| updateNestedFolder newFolderName rest)

      [] ->
        -- no path, so the new folder must be a root folder
        fileSystem
        |> Dict.inset newFolderName (newFolder newFolderName)

{- Recursive update function where the magic happens
-}
updateNestedFolder : FolderName -> List FolderName -> Folder -> Folder
updateNestedFolder newFolderName nodeList (Folder { folderName, childFolders }) =
  case nodeList of
    nextLevel :: rest ->
      -- as long as there is a nodelist, we try to find deeper level
      let
        -- do recursive update on the children
        newChildFolders =
          childFolders
          |> Dict.update nextLevel (Maybe.map <| updateNestedFolder newFolderName rest)
      in
        -- return the updated folder
        Folder
          { folderName = folderName
          , childFolders = newChildFolders
          }

    [] ->
      -- this is the lowest level, so we need to add to this FileSystem
      let
        -- add newFolderName to the child folders
        newChildFolders =
          childFolders
          |> Dict.insert newFolderName (newFolder newFolderName)
      in
        -- return the folder
        Folder
          { folderName = folderName
          , childFolders = newChildFolders
          }

---- HELPERS

{- Create a new folder, without any children -}
newFolder : String -> Folder
newFolder folderName =
  Folder
    { folderName = folderName
    , childFolders = Dict.empty
    }

------ EXAMPLE


fileSystem =
  Dict.fromList
    [ ( "parent1"
      , Folder
        { folderName = "parent1"
        , childFolders =
            Dict.fromList
              [ ( "child1"
                , Folder 
                  { folderName = "child1", childFolders = Dict.empty }
                )
              , ( "child2"
                , Folder 
                  { folderName = "child2", childFolders = Dict.empty }
                )
              , ( "child3"
                , Folder
                  { folderName = "child3"
                  , childFolders =
                      Dict.fromList
                        [ ( "sub-child_of_child3"
                          , Folder 
                            { folderName = "sub-child_of_child3"
                            , childFolders = Dict.empty } 
                          )
                        ]
                  }
                )
              ]
          }
        )
      ]

main =
  text <| toString <| 
    insertFolder 
      "parent1/child3/sub-child_of_child3" 
      "DynamicallyCreated" 
      fileSystem
```

Comment: you are so smart man! :)) Thanks so much, you saved me. I will show you what I'm using this for - once it becomes presentable. In sort, is about programing in elm using voice commands. Maybe you will help me refactor some ideas once the first demo works .. ok, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above worked - but if you have a problem revolving around this idea (not necessarily with dicts) - it's well worth it to look into `how zippers work`.

Zippers are the recommended way to do this sort of walking on dicts, lists, trees. More here: [Learn You A Haskel - Zippers](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) - at the end, is the File System implementation.